# Rails nested resource with respond_with destroy action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the appropriate `respond_with` line for a nested resources destroy action?

My routes:

```
resources :vendors do
  resources :products, :except => [:index]
end
```

Product#destroy (note `@vendor` and `@product` are found with a `before_filter` which is omitted here)

```
def destroy
  @product.destroy 
  respond_with @vendor, @product
end
```

According to my functional tests, this is returning `/vendors/X/products/X` and not `/vendors/X`

Should I change it to just `responed_to @vendor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Rails is smart enough to understand what to do if @product is destroyed

```
respond_with [@vendor, @product]
```

if not, then try this

```
respond_with @product, :location => vendor_path(@vendor)
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct! `respond_with @vendor, @product, :notice => 'Product Deleted'` is even sufficient (notice the lack of the Array)

Comment: @Eduardo Rdm, `@vendor and @product are found with a before_filter which is omitted her`

Comment: The first example takes me to `/vendors/XXX/products` which doesn't exist since I don't have a index route on Products. I guess I need to use the second one... does anyone have a link to the API docs for `respond_with`?

Comment: Then ofcourse use second variant. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

Comment: Able to use `respond_with @vendor, @product, :location => vendor_url(@vendor)` just feels more consistent. I need to find good docs that list all the options available for `respond_with`. Thanks to both you guys for the help!

Comment: @mikeycgto, checkout this http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, that answer was completely wrong (misunderstood your problem):

Your destroy code can be like this:

```
def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.destroy 
  redirect_to <route method for vendor's products index>, :notice => 'Any message'
end
```

See the exact route typing rake routes in your terminal.

params[:vendor_id] should be also available.

Comment: Well I don't have index for products so I guess `vendor_url(@vendor)` would be sufficient?

Comment: yes, that would be fine. or you can just put @vendor, don't need to use the helper method

Comment: You will need to find _at_vendor or use _at_product.vendor